# Converted Currency not showing

Tags: multi-currency

In our org the multi currency feature is enabled with USD and GBP. Currently, USD is the corporate currency and where ever in currency field the dollar value is there like 10 USD, then converted currency in GBP should show.

However, recently we noticed that the converted currency is not showing at all in currency fields though earlier it was showing. Even the parenthetical currency is enabled as well.

Please help in this matter

Comment: COnverted currency is shown only if the record's currency is different from logged in User's currency. if you are logged in user , can you check your currency and then the record currencyisocode field ?

Comment: Hi, I do not think so if it depends on logged in user's currency. in our org most of the users are having default USD currency. However, they were able to see the GBP earlier, but now they can not see. Also, can you let me know if salesforce has referenced anywhere about logged in user's visibility? If I run a report also for converted currency field, i can see the same value as default one.

Comment: Answered the question, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Amit for the valuable information. Yes i think same.

Comment: Kindly up vote and accept so that it helps other too :)

Answer (score 1):

One enabling Multi-Currency, Primary currency will show up as before but now an additional value in parentheses will show the **converted amount** in the secondary currency. 
The primary currency will be the corporate default currency unless overridden per record using fields such as Account Currency, Opportunity Currency, etc. 
The (converted) amount shown is always your personal default currency. Please note, the fields AccountCurrency and Opportunity Currency are only available in [New] and [Edit] mode.
Reference - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003638 
Now can you check first the corporate currency, then the records currency. if these match the User's currency then converted currency will not be shown in paranthesis. TO validate, you can quickly edit one opportunity and change currency to GBP and you will see converted currency immediately (try in sandbox).